# How to loop through a json data from AWS dynamo db using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, amazon-dynamodb, frontend

Pasting the GET api url on a browser shows me the json data. It looks like this:

```
{"Count":2,"Items":[{"date":{"S":""},"time":{"S":""},"email":{"S":"test1@email.com"},"name":{"S":""},"phone":{"S":""},"desc":{"S":""}},{"date":{"S":"3/7/21"},"time":{"S":"8:00am - 9:00am"},"email":{"S":"binia@gmu.edu"},"name":{"S":"Bini A"},"phone":{"S":"1234567890"},"desc":{"S":"I like your cut G"}}],"ScannedCount":2}
```

But When I try to use ajax request to loop through the data, it returns [Object Object]. Please help me figureout this error.
Here is my frontend code:

```js
$.ajax({
                url: 'my URL goes here ...',
                type: "GET",
                
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('data fetched!');
                    
                    var tr = '<tr><th>Full Name</th><th>Phone Number</th><th>Email</th><th>Requested Date</th><th>Requested Time</th><th>Customer Feedback</th></tr>'; // row

                    // loop through data and display on table
                    data.Items.forEach(function (Item) {
                        tr += '<tr><td>' + Item.name + '</td>';
                        tr += '<td>' + Item.phone + '</td>';
                        tr += '<td>' + Item.email + '</td>';
                        tr += '<td>' + Item.date + '</td>';
                        tr += '<td>' + Item.time + '</td>';
                        tr += '<td>' + Item.desc + '</td></tr>';
                    });

                    $('#createdHoursDb').append(tr); // update table
                    
                    console.log(tr);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('fetch request failed!');
                }
            });
```

Here is the response on the page:
[Object Object] on each cell of each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, the value of each property is also an object: `"name":{"S":""}`

So you can write:

```js
...
data.Items.forEach(function (Item) {
  tr += '<tr><td>' + Item.name.S + '</td>';
  tr += '<td>' + Item.phone.S + '</td>';
  tr += '<td>' + Item.email.S + '</td>';
  tr += '<td>' + Item.date.S + '</td>';
  tr += '<td>' + Item.time.S + '</td>';
  tr += '<td>' + Item.desc.S + '</td></tr>';
});
...
```

Comment: thanks. this works perfectly. apparently I was missing the .S in each data

Comment: @BiniTutor That's great. Can you please consider marking it as accepted then?

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing `object` because you have an object inside it `{"S": ""}`. Either you need to convert your data in the required form or you need to use like `Item.name.S` everywhere.

```js
const data = {"Count":2,"Items":[{"date":{"S":""},"time":{"S":""},"email":{"S":"test1@email.com"},"name":{"S":""},"phone":{"S":""},"desc":{"S":""}},{"date":{"S":"3/7/21"},"time":{"S":"8:00am - 9:00am"},"email":{"S":"binia@gmu.edu"},"name":{"S":"Bini A"},"phone":{"S":"1234567890"},"desc":{"S":"I like your cut G"}}],"ScannedCount":2};

let tr = '<tr><th>Full Name</th><th>Phone Number</th><th>Email</th><th>Requested Date</th><th>Requested Time</th><th>Customer Feedback</th></tr>'; // row

data.Items.forEach(function (Item) {
                        tr += '<tr><td>' + Item.name.S + '</td>';
                        tr += '<td>' + Item.phone.S + '</td>';
                        tr += '<td>' + Item.email.S + '</td>';
                        tr += '<td>' + Item.date.S + '</td>';
                        tr += '<td>' + Item.time.S + '</td>';
                        tr += '<td>' + Item.desc.S + '</td></tr>';
                    });

                    $('#createdHoursDb').append(tr); // update table
                    
                    console.log(tr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="createdHoursDb">

</table>
```

Comment: How is this differentt from my answer? :D

Comment: Similar answer. much thanks. this works perfectly. apparently I was missing the .S in each data